# How to scroll a modal window on Bootstrap?

Tags: php, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, drupal, bootstrap-modal

I have a site with Drupal 8 and Bootstrap 3

I created a custom module to display a page in a modal window. The page contains a lot of text and I want it to have a scrollbar on the modal window.

How can I do this ? Here is the code of my module and the information I found :

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/modal/#scrolling-long-content

> You can also create a scrollable modal that allows scroll the modal
>   body by adding .modal-dialog-scrollable to .modal-dialog.

I do not even know if my code is correct for Bootstrap or if it can be improved.

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\commerce_marketplace_terms_and_conditions\Plugin\Commerce\CheckoutPane;

use Drupal\Component\Serialization\Json;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\commerce_checkout\Plugin\Commerce\CheckoutPane\CheckoutPaneBase;
use Drupal\commerce_checkout\Plugin\Commerce\CheckoutPane\CheckoutPaneInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Link;
use Drupal\Core\Url;

/**
 * Provides the completion message pane.
 *
 * @CommerceCheckoutPane(
 *   id = "marketplace_terms_and_conditions",
 *   label = @Translation("Marketplace Terms and Conditions"),
 *   default_step = "review",
 * )
 */
class MarketplaceTermsAndConditions extends CheckoutPaneBase implements CheckoutPaneInterface {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildPaneForm(array $pane_form, FormStateInterface $form_state, array &$complete_form) {
    $store_name = $this->order->getStore()->getName();
    $store_id = $this->order->getStoreId();
    $pane_form['#attached']['library'][] = 'core/drupal.dialog.ajax';
    $attributes = [
      'attributes' => [
        'class' => 'use-ajax',
        'data-dialog-type' => 'modal',
        'data-dialog-options' => Json::encode([
          'width' => 'auto'
        ]),
      ],
    ];
    $link = Link::fromTextAndUrl(
      $this->t('terms and conditions of the store "@store_name"', ['@store_name' => $store_name]),
      Url::fromUri("internal:/store/$store_id/cgv", $attributes)
    )->toString();
    $pane_form['marketplace_terms_and_conditions'] = [
      '#type' => 'checkbox',
      '#default_value' => FALSE,
      '#title' => $this->t('I have read and accept @terms.', ['@terms' => $link]),
      '#required' => TRUE,
      '#weight' => $this->getWeight(),
    ];
    return $pane_form;
  }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot how its looking right now? That would help

Comment: @ArturLeinweber Yes I updated my question

Comment: My solution would ve via CSS. Add a height to .modal-body like height:90vh and overflow-y: scroll. That should be a solution for your problem

Comment: @ArturLeinweber Thank you I have already thought about that, but I'm looking for a cleaner solution by inserting the class Bootstrap directly in the code of my question.

Comment: Someone would have a solution ?